# Volume of the cone in terms of sphere radius inside it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I need to find the volume of this cone. I know that there exists a ratio between the basis area and the transvelsar cut made into the sphere in the drawings, such that the ratio between the two áreas is equal to $k/h$ where $h$ is the heigth and $k$ is the distance of the transversal cut to $C$.

I can find $h-k$ but I can't find $k$.

Could you guys help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the height of the cone is $h$ and the radius of the base is $R$, the radius $r$ of the inscribed sphere is given by:
$$ r = \frac{R h}{2R+2\sqrt{R^2+h^2}} $$
and the sphere touches the $AC$ segment in a point $B'$ such that:

$$ 2 CB' + 4 R = 2 R + 2 \sqrt{R^2+h^2}, $$
hence:
$$ \frac{B'C}{AC} = \frac{\sqrt{R^2+h^2}-R}{\sqrt{R^2+h^2}}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{h}{R}\right)^2}}=\kappa.$$
Given $h$ and the last ratio, we have:
$$ \frac{1}{1-\kappa} = \sqrt{1+\frac{h^2}{R^2}},\qquad \frac{\kappa(2-\kappa)}{(1-\kappa)^2}=\frac{h^2}{R^2} $$
hence:
$$ R^2 = \frac{(1-\kappa)^2}{\kappa(2-\kappa)} h^2 $$
and the volume of the cone is given by:

> $$ V = \frac{\pi}{3} R^2 h = \frac{\pi(1-\kappa)^2}{3\kappa(2-\kappa)}h^3.$$